# how to implement grid layout in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-material, material-design, angular-components, angular-dart

I am a java programmer studying dart and angulardart.

Does angulardart officially provide a grid layout style?

Or do I have to use a third party like bootstrap?

If I have to use a third party, what best fits your angular dart?

The Material Design specification has a grid system and I thought it was in angulardart.

But the official implementation does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official implementation of a grid layout style in angular-dart. So you'll need to import your grid of choice.

If you are looking for a Material Design style it's worth knowing there are a useful set of Material design components maintained by Google, but sadly no grid on there as yet - and not on the road map yet. See here:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_components#-readme-tab-

See here for the current list of components: https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components/

I like the Zurb Foundation grid, which you can split out from the rest of foundtion and download as pure css - but that's purely a personal choice based on using Foundation for years. Angular Dart is styled with css so you can use any css grid system you like.